# PHP create_function result stored as instance variable, and called as $object->func()?

Tags: php, anonymous-function, create-function

I'm using PHPs `create_function($args, $code)` function to dynamically load a function definition from a database.

The way I'm attempting to implement it is as follows:

I have a class `MyClass` which has an instance variable `myFunction`. The constructor populates that instance variable with the result of a call to `create_function`. I'm hoping to dynamically create a function for the specific object (once instantiated) of this class, that can be called as `$object->myFunction(arg1, arg2);`

So my class looks like:

```
class MyClass {

     public $myFunction = '';

     public function __construct() {
         $this->myFunction = //return function body from DB call.
     }


}
```

I'm then trying to call this dynamic function from elsewhere in my program on the instantiated "MyClass" object by doing something like...

```
$object = new MyClass();
$object->myFunction(args..);
```

However I keep getting errors such as:

```
MyClass and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named myFunction.
```

When I run `var_dump($object->myFunction)` I get back "lambda_xx", which is a good sign meaning `create_function` is at least working.

---

**Interesting Update on Works vs. Doesn't Work cases**

It turns out that in my "other file" where I am doing the following:

```
   $pm = Yii::app()->user->postMatching; //This is a PostMatching object made elsewhere
    $c = $pm->findRelated;

    foreach ($posts as $post) {

        var_dump($c);

        $postIds = $c($post, $limit);

        //post to related mapping
        $specificRelatedPostIds[$post->postId] = $postIds;

    }
    exit; // exiting for testing
```

This doesn't work, but if instead of pulling the object `$pm` from `Yii::app()->user->postMatching` I just create a new one:

```
$pm = new PostMatching();
$c = $pm->findRelated; //the anon function instance variable

$c(); // THIS WORKS NOW!
```

So naturally I var_dumped `$pm` and `$c` in both the "newly created" case and the case where I get it from `Yii::app()->user->postMatching`, and they are identical. The only thing that is different is the name of the anonymous function (as expected).

Does anyone have any idea why this might be the case? In both cases `$pm` IS an instantiated `PostMatching` object with that instance variable, I'm just unable to use the syntax to invoke it!

---

Just updated the above with newly discovered "Twists", thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something along these lines can be useful:

```
class MyClass {

     private $myFunction = '';

     public function __construct() {
         $this->myFunction = //return function body from DB call.
     }

     public function myFunction() {
         $args = func_get_args();
         return call_user_func_array($this->myFunction, $args);
     }

}
```

Comment: I get the error "call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function '' not found or invalid function name." when trying the above. If I var_dump($this->myFunction) I get "lambda_xx", so its not like its empty.... *puzzled*

Comment: Try `call_user_func_array(array($this,myFunction), $args)`

Comment: @Levi Since `$this->myFunction` is just a string denoting the name of a regular global function, that *shouldn't* be necessary. :-?

Comment: The value of `$this->myFunction` may be regular and global, but to access it you still need to use the array syntax, I believe.

Comment: @deceze I just updated the bottom of the question above - found some new weird behavior. (I.e. if i create a new object in the same block and call it its fine... but otherwise not)

Answer (score 2):

That's due to parsing-related troubles that PHP has. This version should work:

```
$object = new MyClass();
$method = $object->myFunction;
$method(args..);
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/Jq2pc)**.

Comment: I tried that syntax, but the call itself still won't fire. If I var_dump ($method) in this case, I get "lambda_xx", but if I call $method(arg1, arg2) it errors. Is $method in this case referring specifically to the $object's method?.. or would I need something like $object->$method (also tried and failed). Note: I'm making these calls to the anon function in a loop, but $method itself is instantiated prior to the loop.

Comment: @csjohn: That's not possible unless the working example is different code than yours. In which case, please post your real code.

Comment: I added real code relating to this issue in the question above. Thanks!

Comment: @csjohn: OK, saw it and have to ask: *why* are you exposing a property instead of a method?!? Why not `function findRelatedPosts($post, $limit) { ... }`?

Comment: At this point im just trying to get it to work. Once I get passed the barrier I'll write a public method to wrap the dynamic instance variable anonymous method and call like that.

Comment: @csjohn: But doing that would immediately solve your problem!

Comment: I thought so too, i've tried wrapping it. In that case the call does get "in" to the wrapper function, but when it gets to the line to actually invoke the anonymous function, it errors in the same fashion. I've updated my above question (Towards the bottom) with some new information and quirks on my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can call the method like this:

```
call_user_func($object->myFunction, args..);
```